# How to add data to a td cell in a table in a div

Tags: javascript, gopherjs

I am using gopherjs to accompish this task.
I only need to change data in one cell. But I have severally similar templates.
I can add data to any element by id. But in this case, I am wondering if I am doing something wrong.
Right now I am just getting the element by id directly, but I am wondering if I need to be more specific about the row, table and div.
I have the following table:

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2>Search results</h2>
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Results</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td align="result" id="expirydata">John</td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

I only need to change the epirydata cell. Do I need to give the row an id? Do I also need a table Id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I have never worked with gopherjs.

IDs in HTML are supposed to be unique within a web page. the function getElementById depends on it. If you need to programmatically modify always the same cell based on the same template occurring in multiple places within a page, here are your options:

1. have parametrized/configurable ID. Pass it into your template and getElementById accordingly. Upside: easy to implement. Downside: hard to maintain due to leaky abstraction and having to manage all the IDs outside the templates.
2. have a template builder method, which will accept a content as a function parameter and will output the template with already replaced content. Upside: implementation details encapsulated. Downside: with larger templates you degrade performance and might have to introduce caching of parameters if there will be multiple placeholders to fill into.
3. parametrize the template by putting ID into the top-level element in your template, e.g. table or a div. Don't use ID in the nested elements, rather use class to navigate within the ID element using the [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) function. This gives you flexibility, maintainability and reusability.

I assume you use `.innerHTML = 'content'` approach. Beware of the XSS attacks.

4. Modern frameworks like react or angular go the 2) way and handle/offer the performance the optimizations as well as the security aspect out of the box. There might be other frameworks/view libraries which might be slimmer and/or work in coordination with gopherjs. Try to look for these.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I have all these options. I am using .innerHTML. I think I will just focus on ids and queryselector for now to make things easy.

Answer (score 1):

```
const table = document.querySelector("table");
    table.rows[1].cells[0].textContent = "changed_text";
//First find table by tagname or class name.
//then travel into table by its rows and cells number
```

Comment: This looks like a good approach. I will try it.